# Python 2.7 telnetlib For Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, telnetlib

I am writing a simple script in python , to telnet multiple cisco switches and add vlans. I am testing my script in UNET LABS or latest EVE-NG. 
When I telnet to multiple switches using FOR loop and call 
 tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
from with in loop , it only telnets to last value in variable HOST i.e. 10.1.1.7

Here is my code,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

user = raw_input("Enter your telnet username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()


for h in range (2,8):
    print "Telnet to host" + str(h)
    HOST = "10.1.1." + str(h)
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

    tn.read_until("Username: ")
    tn.write(user + "\n")
    if password:
        tn.read_until("Password: ")
        tn.write(password + "\n")

    tn.write("conf t\n")

    for n in range (10,20):
        tn.write("vlan " + str(n) + "\n")
```

Comment: Just copy pasting and running your code results in the output `Telnet to host 2` as this host doesn't exist here nothing happens, but it clearly starts with host 2. Can you post the output of your run or is it only the telnet that's acting strange and the printed output looks ok?

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me. Put all of your IPs in a sheet (IP_test.txt).

```
    import getpass
    import sys
    import telnetlib
    user = "YOURUSER"
    password = "YOURPASSWORD"
    with open('IP_test.txt') as file:
            for HOST in file:
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
        tn.read_until("login: ")
        tn.write(user + "\n")
        if password:
            tn.read_until("Password: ")
            tn.write(password + "\n")
            tn.write("Command1\n")
            tn.write("Command2\n")
            print(tn.read_all())
```

Answer (score 0):

This python script below works for me for the same purpose

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import getpass
import telnetlib
user = input("Enter your Telnet Username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

DeviceList=open('/home/tt/Hostname.txt')
for HOST in DeviceList:
    print('Configuring on Device : ',HOST)
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
    tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    if password:
        tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
        tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        tn.write(b"enable\n")
        EnPass=input('Enter your Enable password : ')
        tn.write(EnPass.encode('ascii')+b'\n')
        c=open('/home/tt/Commands.txt')
        for i in c:
            tn.write(i.encode('ascii')+b'\n')
        c.close()
        print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
        tn.close()
DeviceList.close()}
```